# Correctly type function that returns the first property of an object Typescript

Tags: typescript

I have the following function that returns the first property on the object:

```
const firstProp = (object: Record<string, unknown>) =>
  object[Object.keys(object)[0]];
```

I would like to type the function so that its return type matches the property type. Any ideas?

Comment: There isn't really a standard definition of what a first property of an object is, hence you can't really base type definitions on it.

Comment: There's no ordering to TS object types so the best you could do is get a union of known types as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/we6aVN). Except, as shown, that also isn't really accurate because values can have excess properties so the best you can *safely* do is just return `unknown`.  Does this fully address your question? If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Okay, thank you both for clearing that up. Makes sense but it does seem like a bit of a missing feature, since JavaScript does allow for iterating objects using `Object.keys()`, `Object.entries()`, etc... My particular use case is I have a dictionary of named arrays (the names are important), all of the same length, & want to iterate through them, so I just grab the first array & use its indices.

Comment: Are the types of the arrays the same or different?  Maybe you could show a [mre] of the code you actually need to run.  The version I showed you will take a `Record<string, unknown[]>` and return an `unknown[]`, which should be sufficient for your needs unless I'm misunderstanding.

Answer (score -1):

You would define the return type outside of the function's `()` params using the `:` separator. I'm not sure what your types are so excuse the crude example.

Define "what" the function returns. For example `const fn = (): number => { return 1; }` returns a number.

**In your case something like:**

```
type ReturnT = Record<string, unknown>;
type ObjectT = Record<string, unknown>;

const firstProp = (object: ObjectT): ReturnT => object[Object.keys(object)[0]];
```

If the return type is the exact same as the input object type, you can use the same type reference as well.